# condition number of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

To my knowledge, there are no explicit formulas linking the singular values of a matrix sum to the singular values of the summand matrices, i.e. it is hard to guess the singular values of matrix $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}$ knowing the singular values of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

My question is, what if $\mathbf{B} = \alpha\mathbf{I}_N$, where $\alpha$ is some constant and $\mathbf{I}_N$ is the identity matrix.

Can we write the singular values of $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}+\alpha\mathbf{I}_N$ as function of those of matrix $\mathbf{A}$?

*(Please notice that I am asking about the singular values, **not** the eigenvalues).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider e.g. $A_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ and $A_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ 
which both have singular values $0$ and $1$.  But $A_1 + I$ and $A_2 + I$ do not have the same singular values.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the prompt reply and for the counter-example. How about an inequality ? Allow me to explain the motivation behind questions. Computer simulations suggest an improved (smaller) condition number of C compared with A (at least on the average), and the improvement is increasing with $\alpha$. For the condition number w.r.t. the eigenvalues, one can easily prove that conditon number of  $\mathbf{C}$ $\leq$ condition numbre of $\mathbf{A}$, but I'm interested in the condition number wrt the singular values $K=\frac{\sigma_{max}}{\sigma_{min}}$. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: For $A$ that has an eigenvalue $-1$, condition number of $A + \alpha I$ certainly doesn't improve with increasing $\alpha$ in $[0,1]$.  Or are you making some assumptions on $A$?

Comment: Hi Robert , thanks for the clarification. how about A having Gaussian i.i.d entries, say with zero mean and unit variance ? Thanks in advance for your kind follow up and assistance.